# Remove .jpg extension from path

Tags: php

What is the less expensive solution to remove ".jpg" extension from path, for example

```
lib/img/img.jpg  > lib/img/img
```

I will use it in loop 6 times, thats why i need a lightweight solution.

Comment: try `rtrim('lib/img/img.jpg','.jpg')` .. and 6 times is like .. nothing .. 600.000 times would make more sense .. and nex time, please post your _tried_ code first .. I'm being nice today ;)

Comment: Dude, your answer is wrong. rtrim will remove all car from the list. The result of your solution will be : `lib/img/im`

Comment: @MatRt Dude, tell me why. Cause of the possible other thousand extensions you might want to remove?

Comment: Did you read what I just wrote ? your solution is removing the last `g`. trim is not a good solution because it is not doing a cut, it will remove all char from the list, and stop only when no char is corresponding to the list, and this is not what we need here.

Comment: @MatRt Indeed it is ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pathinfo` native method is probably your best bet. The output is an array with components that you can then piece back together:

```
$parts = pathinfo("lib/img/img.jpg");
$result = $parts['dirname'] . '/' . $parts['filename'];
```

`$result` now contains your massaged filename.

Comment: I've always wanted a massaged filename.

Comment: please can you tell me if this might be useful @Cody caughlan :)
and what type of matters may occurred using this solution ?

<?php
$impath = "lib/img/img.jpg";
$imwithoutext = substr($impath,0,strrpos($impath,"."));
echo $imwithoutext;
?>

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, six isn't much. Start optimizing when you have a loop that runs a thousand times at least.

Having said that, you're looking for [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function.